# English (latin) characters in Chinese texts look odd

Tags: fonts

I have noticed on some websites from China and other maybe some other countries, have some English text mixed in with them, but the font looks rough and stretched out. Here is an example from Microsoft Answers (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/%EF%BD%86%EF%BD%8F%EF%BD%8E%EF%BD%94/58918cdb-780c-46a2-9dbc-a35e813299c1) : Ｉｎ　ｆａｃｔ，　ｗｈｅｎ　Ｉ　ｓｔａｒｔｅｄ　ｔｙｐｉｎｇ　ｔｈｉｓ　ｖｅｒｙ　ｐａｒａｇｒａｐｈ　ｔｈｅ　ｆｏｎｔ　ｗｅｎｔ　ｂａｃｋ　ｔｏ　ｎｏｒｍａｌ　ｆｏｒ　ａ　ｗｈｉｌｅ，　ｂｕｔ　ｎｏｗ　ｉｔ　ｉｓ　ａｌｌ　ｓｔｒｅｔｃｈｅｄ　ｏｕｔ　ａｇａｉｎ。 Why does this happen in a lot of places, and what is this font called? Could I enable this font on my PC? It looks a bit like times new roman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the ｆｕｌｌｗｉｄｔｈ forms of Unicode. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms) for more info.